# I can't upload a war file by wildfly 10 because of missing dependencies

Tags: java, jersey, wildfly

I tried to upload an application called app.war to wildfly 10 server. This wildfly was turned on using java 1.8u172.
On the other side, I generated the war file using Netbeans. The java platform to build the war file  is also java 1.8u172.

The POM file has the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
        <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>         
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

Web.xml content:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
        <!-- REST API -->
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
                <param-value>true</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

The war file couldn't be uploaded. Wildfly shows the following messages:

```
    Cannot upload deployment: {
            "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./app" 
            => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./app: 
            java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 19457 out of bounds for length 10921 
            Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 19457 out of bounds for length 10921"},
            "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./app"],
            "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined}
```

I prefer to make it works using java 1.8u172 without upgrading jerssey library. The idea is knowing the reason why the uploading it's not working.
How can I figure it out the missing dependencies or What can I do for this case?

**Added 1:**

By Netbeans, I created the folder META-INF inside webapps folder. Then I created the jboss-deployment-structure.xml file with the content as follows:

jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<deployment>
    <exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
    </exclude-subsystems>
</deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Even though, I couldn't upload the war file. I'll show Wildfly log

Wildfly Server.log

```
2023-11-30 10:10:42,086 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 98) MSC000001: 
    Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./app: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException 
    in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./app: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 19457 out of bounds for length 10921
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 19457 out of bounds for length 10921
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:133)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.JarFileScanner.scan(JarFileScanner.java:97)
    ... 

2023-11-30 10:10:42,106 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "app.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./app" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException 
    in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./app: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 19457 out of bounds for length 10921
    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 19457 out of bounds for length 10921"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./app"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
2023-11-30 10:10:42,106 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "app.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./app" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./app: 
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 19457 out of bounds for length 10921
    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 19457 out of bounds for length 10921"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./app"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
2023-11-30 10:10:42,415 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment app.war (runtime-name: app.war) in 304ms
2023-11-30 10:10:42,415 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."app.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."app.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."app.war".component."com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.Include".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."app.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."app.war".component."com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."app.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."app.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."app.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."app.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."app.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."app.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."app.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./app (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."app.war".deploymentCompleteService]
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use Jersey directly? WildFly provides RESTEasy for it's Jakarta REST implementation.

Comment: Jersey is part of the implementation and It's not a requeriment to change it.

Comment: Then you're going to have to exclude the `jaxrs` subsystem with a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` from your deployment. I don't know what parts of Jersey you'll need however.

Comment: I put the 'Added 1' in the post with details of adding jboss-deployment-structure.xml but it's still not working.

Comment: It's tough to tell what it would be. I don't know what Jersey dependencies are needed to get Jakarta REST working in a different container.